# ¿Cómo asignar anchos diferentes a texto de un option de select multiple?

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

Dar un espacio definido como una tabla a cada opción es decir, primer valor `30px`; segundo valor `30px`; tercer valor `60px`; étc.

El problema es que cada campo tiene una longitud diferente y no he podido alinearlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De tal manera quede como el estilo de una tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$.each(response[1], function( index, value ) {
  var _text = '<span style="width:10px;">'+value.name_office+'</span>'+
              '<span style="width:40px;">'+value.label'</span>'+
              '<span style="width:50px;">'+value.label_address+'</span>'+
              '<span style="width:60px;">'+total_amount_authorized+'</span>'+
              '<span style="width:80px;">'+value.balance_due_total+'</span>';

  var  text = '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+_text+'</option>';

  $('#select_contract_assign').append(text);
});
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo actual

Comment: `$.each(response[1], function( index, val ) {
                var _text='<span style="width:10px;">'+val.name_office+'</span>'+
       '<span style="width:40px;">'+val.label'</span>'+
       '<span style="width:50px;">'+val.label_address+'</span>'+
       '<span style="width:60px;">'+val.total_amount_authorized+'</span>';
                
              
                
var  text ='<option value="'+value.id+'">'+_text+'</option>';
$('#select_contract_assign').append(text);
             
             });`

Comment: Es mucho mejor que edites tu pregunta y ahi coloque el codigo

Comment: No puedes hacer eso con un multiselect, la etiqueta <option> no admite codigo html dentro, Tiene que ser a puro javascript.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, es verdad no se puede agregar mas etiquetas html dentro de un option, por lo que tuve que recurrir a jquery selectable el cual me permite tener mucha mas comodidad en el uso de select multiples. Espero alguien más le sea util: http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid

Comment: @SRFSRF quizá deberías agregar ese comentario como una respuesta, para que quede la pregunta cerrada, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, es verdad no se puede agregar mas etiquetas html dentro de un option, por lo que tuve que recurrir a jquery selectable el cual me permite tener mucha mas comodidad en el uso de select multiples. Espero alguien más le sea util: jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid